# sbt: assembly and publishLocal on another project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following structure of two projects -

```
projA
  -- build.sbt
projB
  -- build.sbt
```

projB has a code level dependency on projA (listed as part of libraryDependencies). However it is not okay to make projB as module or sub-project of projA or vice-versa.

I have tasks in projB's build.sbt to create a ZIP bundle (non fat-jar). The ZIP includes libraries and hence projA's JAR.

Everytime I want to build the ZIP in projB I have to make sure that projA is compiled and published to local-ivy-repo. Only after that will my ZIP generated in projB have the **right** JAR for projA.

I want to run the *compile* and *publishLocal* commands of projA from within projB's build.sbt. How can I do this?

Comment: I would recommend to create a parent SBT project:

    projParent
      -- build.sbt
      projA
        -- build.sbt
      projB
        -- build.sbt

... I am sure you know what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be by making `projA` a *project* dependency of `projB` instead of a *library* dependency. I.e. in `projB/build.sbt`

```
lazy val projA = RootProject("../projA")

lazy val projB = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(projA)
```

This ensures that `compile` in projB will automatically call `compile` in projA and similarly for other commands.

See [Multi-Project Builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) in SBT documentation.